# java swing focusGained modal dialog does not stop actionPerfomed events on underlying frame

Tags: java, swing, events, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a java swing application where I want the user to input some text just before the actionPerformed event on a JButton is executed. To do so, I add a focus listener on the button which creates a modal dialog which reads the user's text input, as shown in the following code sample:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ModularDialogBug {

  static String msg = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bug?");

JButton button = new JButton("press me");

button.addFocusListener(
        new FocusListener() {
  @Override
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    if (e.getOppositeComponent() != null) {
      System.out.println("focusGained");
    }
    //fails to block actionPerformed event on "press me" button:
    msg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "please input msg");
  }

  @Override
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
  }
}
);

button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("actionPerformed");
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, msg);
  }
}
);

JPanel p = new JPanel();

p.add(new JButton("initial focus"));
p.add(button);

frame.add(p);

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The problem is that the dialog created in focusGained is not truely modal, the actionPerformed event is executed (by the event loop of the modal dialog) before the modal dialog returns. If I replace the modal dialog by a blocking operation (e.g. read from stdin), then everything works as expected. 
From my understanding of modal dialogs this seems to be a bug (the actionPerformed should not be executed until the modal dialog returns). Interestingly, this happens on both win7 (64bit java8) and on mint17 (also 64bit java8). 
Is the swing implementation vendor specific or do windows and linux share the same swing code? 
Who is actually responsible for swing bugs, oracle?
Also, I have not found any clear definition how modality is implemented in swing, so maybe the behavior is as intended? I read that somehow some events are blocked from execution when a modal dialog is running.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature. You simply need to move your code for input dialog in your action.

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, msg);`?

Comment: From the JavaDocs *"parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used"* - the "default" frame, from memory, is an invisible frame created by `JOptionPane` API

Comment: Of course, I checked the docs myself and tried setting the frame like: 
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, msg);
It makes no difference (it just determines where the dialog is centered). If null is specified as frame, then the dialog is modal with regard to all other frames, at least that is what I read. So it should work with either frame or null, but it works in neither case.